# How to Pessimistic lock then hold indefinitely in order to track who's master in a cluster?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, ejb, jpa-2.0

I thought this would be really simple but so far I have not managed this. I have a tomcat cluster and I want to assign a master.

I was thinking a race between nodes to lock a table. Whoever locks it is master. The master must now keep that lock. The other nodes should try to acquire the lock...

I don't mind pure JDBC but the application is using JPA and EJB (TomEE)

How to lock?
How to hold lock?
how to wait to acquire lock indefinitely if already locked?

OK I managed to get it to "wait forever" but now I am scared because when reading the docs I get the impression it should not wait at all so I don't feel like I am in control...

This is my deadlock using Eclipselink:

```
    Map<String, Object> timeout = new HashMap<>();
    timeout.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 1L);
    master = entityManager.find(Master.class, "MASTER", LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ, timeout);
```

the timeout flag is also specified in persistence.xml...

Comment: http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4349.page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the lock, use `javax.persistence.LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` and `EntityMode`'s `lock()` method (or any of the methods that take a lock mode). You can hold the lock by not letting the transaction complete (either via commit or rollback).

To keep retrying the lock, I would loop forever with a try-catch to handle the exceptions as they occur and try again to get the lock. Note that depending on your isolation level, you will probably have to clean up your old transaction and start a new one each time you try to get the lock. Set your lock wait timeout to some reasonable duration (say a minute) or `Thread.sleep()` at least briefly between attempts to get the lock so you don't waste a lot of resources trying and failing to get the lock on all of the non-master servers.

You will want to make sure that you don't have any timeouts that will kill the connection or transaction prematurely (both for the "master" and all of the non-masters that are trying to become the master).

You will also want to make sure that you properly handle the "master" changing (it will happen eventually) in an automated way, so when another server manages to get the lock it takes over all the "master" business logic.

Comment: This is what I had in mind :-) Problem is that PESSIMISTIC_WRITE and PESSIMISTIC_READ both seem to have no effect on reading the row.

However when i use PESSIMISTIC_WRITE and try to update the row I get a deadlock with Eclipselink. I tried setting: 

    <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="1" />

but it did not help. Also I would prefer if even blocked reads...

Comment: OK figured out what I did wrong. Now it deadlocks on read. However I can't understand why it does not throw Exception instead of deadlocking. See updated question

Comment: I will create new question